# Axis2 Java - ADB array members not being serialized in request

Tags: java, arrays, wsdl, axis

I have an Axis2 client application which relies a wsdl2java generated stub / proxy class. I specified the ADB databinding format when generating the java classes for my client.

I have a web method which takes in 1 to many complex elements I've defined in an XML schema. When I add them to my collection and pass that into the stub method to make the request, the objects are not being serialized. Here's an example of my client code -

```
DBSchema_type0 schema = new DBSchema_type0();
schema.setSchemaName(txtASSchemaName.getText());
SchemaRequest req = new SchemaRequest();
req.addDBSchema(schema);
GenericResponse resp = rwStub.addSchema(req);
```

So from my investigation thus far it seems that the SchemaRequest method is being serialized as expected, however the inner collection is not. The addDBSchema method doesn't do any kind of serialization so I'm guessing that may be the problem.

Is there another generated method I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find out why this was happening however I've experienced issues with axis data binding several times up to this point.

I switched to XML beans and my collections serialized without issue.